# Sidebar until bottom in HTML

Tags: html, css

My friend is working on his website, but he has a problem with his sidebar. He wants the sidebar to go until the bottom of the page and not the bottom of the visible part in the browser. [Here is the link to the page](http://www.mitchelldesmet.be/antwerpengooit/).

Can someone please help?

Comment: Has everyone forgotten about the old school [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sidebar to reach the bottom of the page, the sidebar and all of it's parent elements need to do the same. Meaning they all need to (in this case) be `height: 100%;`

In your case you need your html, body, #container, and #sidebar to all be `height: 100%;`

***PS:*** On a sidenote, arguably it may be more appropriate for your sidebar to be an `<aside>` rather than an `<article>`.